# Minecraft Bedrock Server and Minecraft on Same PC - Minecraft doesn't see server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was hoping to get information from the same question in another location but it never got answered and posting another question to it wasn't allowed.  So I'll just ask it again.

Windows 10
Minecraft Windows/Bedrock Edition - whatever it is called

1. I installed, setup, and ran the server on my main PC on my home network.
2. My son fired up Minecraft on his computer also on the home network.
3. He was able to easily connect to the server.
4. I then connected to it on my Android phone with no problems.
5. Since that worked I bought another copy of Minecraft to play on my PC, the same PC running the server.
6. Minecraft on my PC doesn't even see it...there are no options for LAN under the friends tab.
7. I read in the "bedrock_server_how_to.html" and in the other question here that I might need to run a command in the CMD as admin, but neither location mentions any special instructions other than that.
8. I ran that command, in CMD, as admin.  CMD responded with "OK"
9. I tried this with the server running and it didn't work.
10. I then closed the server and tried it again, fired the server back up, fired Minecraft back up, still no luck.

How exactly should I get Minecraft on my machine to see the server?  Everyone else on the network can see it.  Internet works fine.  My old TF2 server works fine and I can play it from this machine. Etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

Launch **Windows PowerShell** as an administrator and type the following command:

CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe"

Hit enter, see "OK" and you're done. Relaunch. Also, use 127.0.0.1 instead of "localhost" (unclear why I had to) and make sure the port is accurate for your server setting.

Comment: The other Loopback command never worked for me but this one ended up fixing it. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me thx !

Answer (score 3):

UWP Loopback
By default, Windows 10 prevents UWP applications from accessing a loopback connection with "localhost" (i.e. network resources running on the same machine). You will need to enable loopback for Minecraft for Windows 10 if both of the following conditions are satisfied:

You are hosting the server on a Windows 10 PC.

You want to connect to the server as a client using the same Windows 10 PC that is hosting the server.

Refer to Microsoft's documentation for additional information about UWP loopback.

Enable UWP Loopback
Enabling UWP loopback requires a PC user account with administrator privileges.

Using an administrator account
Press the WIN + R keys to open the Run dialog.

Type cmd.

Select "OK", or press the return or enter key to open the Command Prompt.

Type the following command:

CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt –a –p=S-1-15-2-1958404141-86561845-1752920682-3514627264-368642714-62675701-733520436

Using a standard account
Type "Command Prompt" in the Windows search bar.

Right-click on "Command Prompt" from the results.

Select "Run as administrator".

Enter administrator account credentials.

Type the following command:

CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt –a –p=S-1-15-2-1958404141-86561845-1752920682-3514627264-368642714-62675701-733520436

Comment: I've followed these steps a few times and it doesn't work.  I also found some additional Microsoft documentation that had another step to enable the loopback and it appeared I needed to do that before running this command, so I tried that and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Before you try anything complicated, instead of joining the server with [yourip]:[port], join with localhost:[port] to tell it to join the server hosted on your computer.

If that doesn't work, You would probably have to run the Minecraft Server in a VM using something like VirtualBox to let you join & host the server, since it probably isn't normally supported.